# How to create multiple items at once in Sharepoint using REST API?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I tried using this body:

```json
{
    "value": [
        {
            "fields": {
                "field1": "1",
                "field2": "11",
                "field3": "111"
            }
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "field1": "2",
                "field2": "12",
                "field3": "112"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And I got the `Status Code 201` although it creates only one item with empty data.

My code:

```py
import requests

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<mysite>/lists/<mylist>/items?expand=fields"

payload = "{\r\n    \"value\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"fields\": {\r\n                \"UserId\": \"1\",\r\n                \"ListId\": \"11\",\r\n                \"Fixture_x0020_Id\": \"111\"\r\n            }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"fields\": {\r\n                \"UserId\": \"2\",\r\n                \"ListId\": \"12\",\r\n                \"Fixture_x0020_Id\": \"112\"\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}"
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Nothing related to bulk insert is found on Microsoft Official Documentation.
[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-create?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0
I will try and if I got success I answer here!

Answer (score 0):

It worked using batch requests:

Send a `POST` request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch`

[Official Documentation - Combine multiple requests in one HTTP call using JSON batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer $access_token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "requests": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/sites/<mysite>/lists/<mylist>/items",
            "body": {
                "fields": {
                    "UserId": "1",
                    "ListId": "11",
                    "Fixture_x0020_Id": "111"
                }
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/sites/<mysite>/lists/<mylist>/items",
            "body": {
                "fields": {
                    "UserId": "133",
                    "ListId": "1123",
                    "Fixture_x0020_Id": "1242411"
                }
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
        },
      ...,
      {
            "id": "4",
            "method": "POST",
            "url": "/sites/<mysite>/lists/<mylist>/items",
            "body": {
                "fields": {
                    "UserId": "1DSDS",
                    "ListId": "1464651",
                    "Fixture_x0020_Id": "1JGMJGMG11"
                }
            },
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              }
        }
    ]
}'
```